# Ветвления if и мой пример

Tags: java

друзья! Дали задание сделать ветвления в Java, так вот хотел бы спросить правильно ли сделан мой код или нет:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int age = 13;
    if (age == 25) {
        if (age == 33) {
            if (age == 50) {
                System.out.println("Igor");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код с циклом - скажем. Безотносительно цикла, код - жесть. Вы понимаете, что он делает? А что он должен делать?

Comment: @Igor, иронично, что под вопросом отписались именно Вы)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я тоже обратил на это внимание. Мораль: не поминай имени его всуе.

Comment: Проверяет 3 условия, а потом выдает Error. Вот хотел узнать, вроде правильно работает, но может есть какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: Он не проверяет три условия! Он проверяет только одно условие -- `(age == 25)`. Это условие никогда не выполняется, поэтому никогда не выполняется и все то, что вложено в него (включая все остальные проверки). А циклом здесь и не пахнет -- цикл -- это другое, это когда кусок кода выполняется (или может выполниться при каких-то условиях) более одного раза (так сказать, "по кругу ходит", отсюда и название). Для трёх разных типов цикла есть специальные операторы -- `for`, `do` и `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Цикл" сделан неправильно. Замените его на гораздо более простой код:

```
    if (age != 25) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Comment: А почему неправильно? Получается если первые 3 условия проходят - выдаёт Igor, а если нет, то Error. Разве не так? Можно пошагово объяснить пожалуйста :)

Comment: @ПетровИван Объясняю пошагово: при каком значении `age` выполнение дойдет до проверки третьего условия `age == 50`?

Comment: Так он просто упадет в else и всё, зачем ему доходить до 50?

Comment: @ПетровИван При каком значении `age` Ваш код выведет "Igor"?

Comment: Не при каком получается

Comment: @ПетровИван Зачем он тогда нужен?

Comment: Получается у меня всегда до конца в if(ах) он должен дойти и потом только else, так получается? А если я специально сделал акцент на else, чтобы он именно Error всегда выводил, все равно неправильно?

Comment: @ПетровИван Вы можете словами объяснить, что должен делать код?

Comment: Я всё понял Игорь, спасибо :)

Comment: @ПетровИван Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.